# Gmail built in pdf viewer omits last symbol in an url, any idea why?

Tags: pdf, viewers, bugs, amsrefs, email

Using `amsrefs`, I want to refer to [an answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/313198/41291). That site has automated amsrefs entry creation option. When I use it, everything goes fine, and the pdf file contains correct link. However when I send the file by gmail and open it in gmail with either Chrome or Firefox (latest build, on Windows 10), there is a problem with that link. If I copy it and paste elsewhere it is correct, but if I click on it, I am taken to a wrong address: instead of `https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198` I get `https://mathoverflow.net/q/31319` which is an entirely different page.

MWE: produce a pdf from

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

$\binom nk$

\begin{biblist}
\bib{E}{misc}{
author={Noam D. Elkies (https://mathoverflow.net/users/14830/noam-d-elkies)},
note={URL: https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198 (version: 2018-10-19)}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{document}
```

send it to, say, yourself via gmail and open it from within the gmail pdf viewer.

Let me add that with any other math command that I tried in place of that `$\binom nk$` the error disappears.

What can I do?

Comment: If you want a link in the PDF you should mark it with `\url{....}` and use `hyperref` your PDF has no link just some text so you are relying on the pdf reader to make a non-standard guess that something that looks like a link is a link.

Comment: I'm able to verify this. However, if you download the file and use a dedicated PDF viewer, the links work as expected. This is therefore dependent on the Gmail PDF viewer and not something to do with (La)TeX. Weird though...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thanks. But is not it strange that this guess is influenced by the presence of `$\binom nk$` nearby? Because other kinds of commands (like `$\frac nk$` for example) do not cause this error.

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's true. Still, with the tag [tag:viewer] the question is relevant I believe. And, many thanks for the verification!

Comment: well since there is no link in the file, _any_ link added by the viewer is a mildly annoying none standard guess of a viewer ignoring the spec and assuming it can be helpful by ignoring the authors intentions of making a plain text expression that happens to look like a URL.

Comment: A tag doesn't imply on-topic-ness. It just identifies a mechanism for characterising questions. Regardless, I'd imagine this question is specific to the Gmail viewer, and therefore Gmail's support team might be more inclined to answer here and the technical details involved in a solution might be a patch to their viewer (which falls outside the scope of this network).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aha. Actually when I copy form the gmail viewer I am copying the text of the link (which is correct), not the link (which is incorrect).

Comment: @Werner Would not a question about problems with, say, `yap` or `winedt` be on topic for this site?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: When it comes to external applications related to (La)TeX, it's borderline on-topic. Decisions about it is made on a case-by-case basis. Let's assume the answer is: Gmail support team updated their viewer to correctly interpret the PDF hyperlink for this specific case. (1) End users would have to do nothing, since it's related to (say) Chrome. (2) No-one would notice it once a possible browser update becomes the norm and therefore wouldn't benefit *this* community. (3) The solution could be considered a bug fix which should be reported with the author (which *is* off-topic).

Comment: If you ask how to construct a latex file which has a link, that's on topic and Ulrike's answer is the answer. If you ask about your browsers (or gmails) heuristics for guessing links in plain text pdf with no link fields, then really that's off topic, the fact that the pdf was made by tex isn't relevant you'd presumably get the same if the pdf was made by word or whatever.

Comment: @Werner Well I guess until something like that happens this question might serve as a warning that apparently OK links might be wrong in one particular not-so-uncommon viewer. I do this quite frequently - send a pdf of my TeXed stuff by gmail or read pdfs of others with the gmail viewer...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmmm I guess with the first case there might already exist questions/answers about how to do that. So my question is either a duplicate or off-topic. Anyway, if people suggest to close it I would not object I guess...

Comment: Even more odd is that is a redirected address since https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198 leads to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313191/seeking-a-more-symmetric-realization-of-a-configuration-of-10-planes-25-lines-a/313198#313198 HOWEVER back to your issue you could try adding an extra / so it starts `https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198/` then if gmail trims it back like this comment box did (hence the quotes) it will still redirect like https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198 does !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use hyperref and \url if you want real links:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

$\binom nk$

\begin{biblist}
\bib{E}{misc}{
author={Noam D. Elkies (https://mathoverflow.net/users/14830/noam-d-elkies)},
note={URL: \url{https://mathoverflow.net/q/313198} (version: 2018-10-19)}
}
\end{biblist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works that way, thank you. However let me point out that without that `$\binom nk$` it also worked without `hyperref` and without the `\url{...}`

Comment: Without hyperref the pdf viewer has to guess where links are by looking in the page stream - it is quite possible that this heuristic fails if you add or remove stuff to the page.

Comment: Oh I see. Would never suspect that such clever heuristics were involved...